# Is manual, faster than automatic, duplex printing?

Tags: print-design

I'm guessing yes? Automatic duplex flips while it prints every page, but manual duplex can keep printing pages and requires only one manual turnover of pages.

Comment: Be aware, for laser/wax printers - if the printer is *not* duplex capable, there is a high probability damage the fuser will occur by printing the same piece of paper more than once. Fuser's aren't cheap.

Comment: @Scott '*not* duplex capable': do you mean Automatic or Manual Duplex?

Comment: As I commented on SU, my printer can flip a page as fast as it can pull a new one.

Comment: There's no printer marketed as "manual duplex". If the printer can not directly duplex, then it is not duplex capable. In other words, if it wont' flip the sheet and print it twice itself.

Comment: @Scott Please see the last para. at http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/HowToDoTwoSidedPrinting/index.html.

Comment: Greek... in 40 years I've *never* seen a printer, *any printer* advertised as "manual duplex". That's ridiculous to me. In fact it's really borderline "deceptive" in my opinion. Imagine marketing a garden hose as a "Manual Car Wash" or a match as a "Manual Flashlight" or an oven as a "Manual Microwave". I don't know who Mr. Hardwick is but simply because he wrote that on *his* website, that doesn't make it true. If you can provide another, credible source for a printer marketed as "manual duplex" then I'll recant. But to the best of my knowledge, such marketing does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid that there is no simple and clear explanation for duplex printing. The best way is buying a duplex printer. However, the printer companies always wanted customers to pay more money to buy a more expensive duplex printer. It's a pain for me, too. I can provide you some tips to avoid the problem of manual duplex print.

1. Make sure the document arrange with numbers correctly and maintain the blank page if necessary.
2. Preview the "each paper of front and back".
3. Print **Odd pages (forward)** and then **print even pages (Reverse)**.

[image]

(I am not a native English user. I will appreciate if someone correct my English.)